# How to change the name of an android string in all the application

Tags: java, android, eclipse, string, ide

I just finished to realize my first real Android application. The thing is I used an strings.xml file to store my strings, but I just discovered that the way I named them is really bad. 
For instance, when I wanted to write "List of classrooms", I created a string named "class_list" instead of a better formatted name like "label_classroom_list_title (or any other more specific name).
The problem is that I would like to change these names like when I use the refactor function of Eclipse (the name of a variable is change for all references to this variable).
Is it possible using eclipse ? Or maybe another tool ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really a programming question, but...

With Eclipse, right click on the variable name at any one place you see it. The variable should highlight. You'll get a pop-up menu. Choose the Refactor command. You'll get a second pop up menu. Choose the Rename command. Start typing the new variable name and you should be able to see all references updating as you type.

Comment: thank you, in fact I just didn't try to do the refactoring from the java class but only from the string xml file.

Answer (score 1):

If its just a few files try `Ctrl+F` type in the `Find` field, the old variable name and in the `'Replace with'` the new variable name and hit `Replace All`. It works wonders :) you can also change the variable names in selected lines too.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that in **Intellij** using **Refactor** button from by right clicking the View you want to rename in the strings.xml file. Not sure if that works on Eclipse though.